# How do I get my spline based arrows to have rounded ends?

Tags: graphics, splines

I would like to change the how the ends of the spline arrows in my figure are rendered to be "rounded", but

```
Graphics@{CapForm["Round"], Thick, Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {10, 10}}, SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}], .05]}
```

has no effect, yielding.

How do I get my spline based arrows to have rounded ends?

---

If it matters, these will be used as part of `EdgeShapeFunction` in a `Graph`.

[image]

Comment: Use `ArrowHeads` with custom arrow graphics...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another take based on @rasher's comment:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[.02], 
  Arrowheads[{{-.1, 0, Graphics[{Thickness[.02], CapForm["Round"], 
       Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}]}]}, {.2, 1}}], 
  Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {10, 10}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}], .05]}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

> What if the arrow is dashed or dotted?

Overlaying `BSplineCurve` (without `Arrow`) with a transparent `Arrow` with some manual adjustments seems to work:

```
ah = GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> 0.1][{{0.`, 0.`}, 
      {1.`, 0.`}}][[1, 1, 1, 3, 1]];
g1 = Graphics[{Thickness[.03], Red, Dashing[.02], CapForm["Round"], 
    BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {10, 10}}, 
     SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}]}, ImageSize -> 300];
g2 = Graphics[{Thickness[.03], 
    Arrowheads[{{.15, 1, {ah /. FilledCurve[x__] :> {Opacity[1], Red, 
                FilledCurve[x]}, .5}}}],
    Red, Dashing[.02], CapForm["Round"], 
    BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {9.2, 10.05}}, 
      SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}],
    Opacity[0], 
    Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {10, 10}}, 
      SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}]]}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Promising. What if the arrow is dashed or dotted?

Comment: @raxa, I think it would be quite a challenge to play with the `Arrowheads` settings to get `Dotted`  and `Dashed` curves with rounded caps. Perhaps, overlaying  `BSplineCurve` (without Arrow)  with a transparent `Arrow` might work -- but i haven't tried it yet.

Comment: ...  for `Dashed` curves,  although too  manual/ fragile/specific, a modification of `Arrowheads` along the following lines may work: `Graphics[{Thickness[.02], 
  Arrowheads[{{-.1, 0, 
     Graphics[{PointSize[.02], CapForm["Round"], 
       Point[{-.05, 0}]}]}, {.2, 1}}], Dashed, 
  Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {10, 10}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}], .05]}]`

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough version of comment:

```
ah = Graphics[{Line[{{{-1, 1/2}, {.04, .2}}, {{-1, -1/2}, {.04, -.2}}}], 
   Circle[{.01, 0}, .2, {-4/9 Pi, 4/9 Pi}]}]

Graphics@{Arrowheads[{{Automatic, Automatic, ah}}], CapForm["Round"], 
  Thick, Arrow[
   BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {4, 7}, {2, 11}, {10, 10}}, 
    SplineWeights -> {3, 5, 4, 5}], .05]}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to get the butt (start) of the arrow rounded.